# Restarting gnome-shell - KDE programs look ugly

Tags: gnome, kde, window-decorations

I needed to restart my gnome-shell. I did this on the tty1 via

`export DISPLAY=:0.0`
`gnome-shell --replace`

This helps to keep all the open programs, but all KDE program have a different (e.g. ugly) window decorations. Then I tried `kwin --replace` which looked pretty cool for 5 secs and then I found out, this won't work :)

Is there a way to get back the former looks?

(QT and XUL programs still look fine, firefox and others)

Comment: In Gnome shell you can use 'Alt'+'F2' then enter 'r' to restart the shell.

Comment: Wilf: the gnome shell wasn't working that well, so I used the tty. But now I've tried your command, and all programs look fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restart the shell as you did in the TTY using

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
gnome-shell --replace
```

*(An alternative for the second line would be `gnome-shell --replace & disown` so then you can close the TTY)*

Then you can restart it from the shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `r` -  this should resolve problems with the theme.